# Effecient way to find key name in hash with only one key in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, key

I have an array of hashes, each hash containing only one key/value pair.  is there a more efficient way of accessing the key?  This is my ugly solution

```
array_of_hashes = [
  {:some => "stuff"},
  {:other => "stuff"}
  ]

array_of_hashes.each do |hash|
  hash.each do |key, value|
    puts key
end
```

it seems like to me there must be some way of simply saying

```
array_of_hashes.each do |hash|
  puts hash.key # where this would simply access the key
end
```

or possibly

```
array_of_hashes.each do |hash|
  puts hash.keys[0]
end
```

but that still feels a bit sloppy.

Comment: `array_of_hashes.each { |h| puts h.first.first }`

Comment: thanks, I think this is what i was getting at with my second option:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of efficiency you're after, but this at least is very short:

```
hashes = [
  { a: 'a'},
  { b: 'b'},
  { c: 'c'}
]

hashes.flat_map(&:keys)
# => [:a, :b, :c]
```

Comment: This means that you must create the array, then `puts` it, but that's generally better practice than `puts`ing each element (and not creating the array), as you might need the array later. `puts`ing each element is fine when debugging, of course, in which case @mudasobwa's suggestion will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks.  to clarify I'm looking for a method that would be syntactically cleaner for a hash with only one key-value pair, as opposed to methods that assume multiple elements.  It might not even exist, since hashes typically have more than one element, but since I'm new i thought i should check.  Thanks for your help!